# Xamarin AndroidX RecyclerView Adapter

Tags: firebase, xamarin, android-recyclerview, package, androidx

Hi Im new in Xamarin Android development and I've successfully migrated my application to AndroidX without any errors, but when i Add RecyclerView Adapter it gives me a bunch of errors. Any help is much appreciated. Thanks

Steps to reproduce:

1. Added Xamarin AndroidX packages in Nuget
2. Adding RecyclerView Adapter

Here's my packages:

```
<PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Android.Support.Design" Version="28.0.0.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Android.Support.Core.Utils" Version="28.0.0.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Android.Support.CustomTabs" Version="28.0.0.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.AndroidX.Annotation">
      <Version>1.1.0</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.AndroidX.AppCompat">
      <Version>1.1.0</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.AndroidX.Browser">
      <Version>1.2.0</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.AndroidX.CardView">
      <Version>1.0.0</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.AndroidX.Lifecycle.LiveData">
      <Version>2.2.0</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.AndroidX.Media">
      <Version>1.1.0</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.AndroidX.MediaRouter">
      <Version>1.1.0</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.AndroidX.Migration">
      <Version>1.0.2</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Essentials" Version="1.3.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Firebase.Auth">
      <Version>60.1142.1</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Firebase.Common">
      <Version>60.1142.1</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Firebase.Database">
      <Version>60.1142.1</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Google.Android.Material">
      <Version>1.0.0</Version>
    </PackageReference>
```

And Heres my Error:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS0518  Predefined type 'System.Object' is not defined or imported  ApplicationName C:\Users\SuperUser\source\repos\ApplicationName\ApplicationName\Adapter\StorelistAdapter.cs 30  Active
Error   CS1503  Argument 2: cannot convert from 'method group' to 'Action<StorelistAdapterClickEventArgs>'  ApplicationName C:\Users\SuperUser\source\repos\ApplicationName\ApplicationName\Adapter\StorelistAdapter.cs 30  Active
Error   CS0246  The type or namespace name 'System' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)    ApplicationName C:\Users\SuperUser\source\repos\ApplicationName\ApplicationName\Adapter\StorelistAdapter.cs 1   Active
Error   CS0246  The type or namespace name 'Android' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)   ApplicationName C:\Users\SuperUser\source\repos\ApplicationName\ApplicationName\Adapter\StorelistAdapter.cs 3   Active
Error   CS0246  The type or namespace name 'Android' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)   ApplicationName C:\Users\SuperUser\source\repos\ApplicationName\ApplicationName\Adapter\StorelistAdapter.cs 4   Active
Error   CS0246  The type or namespace name 'Android' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)   ApplicationName C:\Users\SuperUser\source\repos\ApplicationName\ApplicationName\Adapter\StorelistAdapter.cs 5   Active
Error   CS0246  The type or namespace name 'RecyclerView' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)  ApplicationName C:\Users\SuperUser\source\repos\ApplicationName\ApplicationName\Adapter\StorelistAdapter.cs 9   Active
Error   CS0518  Predefined type 'System.Object' is not defined or imported  ApplicationName C:\Users\SuperUser\source\repos\ApplicationName\ApplicationName\Adapter\StorelistAdapter.cs 11  Active
Error   CS0246  The type or namespace name 'EventHandler<>' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)    ApplicationName C:\Users\SuperUser\source\repos\ApplicationName\ApplicationName\Adapter\StorelistAdapter.cs 11  Active
Error   CS0518  Predefined type 'System.Object' is not defined or imported  ApplicationName C:\Users\SuperUser\source\repos\ApplicationName\ApplicationName\Adapter\StorelistAdapter.cs 11  Active
Error   CS0518  Predefined type 'System.Void' is not defined or imported    ApplicationName C:\Users\SuperUser\source\repos\ApplicationName\ApplicationName\Adapter\StorelistAdapter.cs 11  Active
Error   CS0518  Predefined type 'System.Void' is not defined or imported    ApplicationName C:\Users\SuperUser\source\repos\ApplicationName\ApplicationName\Adapter\StorelistAdapter.cs 11  Active
Error   CS0518  Predefined type 'System.Object' is not defined or imported  ApplicationName C:\Users\SuperUser\source\repos\ApplicationName\ApplicationName\Adapter\StorelistAdapter.cs 12  Active
Error   CS0246  The type or namespace name 'EventHandler<>' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)    ApplicationName C:\Users\SuperUser\source\repos\ApplicationName\ApplicationName\Adapter\StorelistAdapter.cs 12  Active
Error   CS0518  Predefined type 'System.Object' is not defined or imported  ApplicationName C:\Users\SuperUser\source\repos\ApplicationName\ApplicationName\Adapter\StorelistAdapter.cs 12  Active
Error   CS0518  Predefined type 'System.Void' is not defined or imported    ApplicationName C:\Users\SuperUser\source\repos\ApplicationName\ApplicationName\Adapter\StorelistAdapter.cs 12  Active
Error   CS0518  Predefined type 'System.Void' is not defined or imported    ApplicationName C:\Users\SuperUser\source\repos\ApplicationName\ApplicationName\Adapter\StorelistAdapter.cs 12  Active
Error   CS0518  Predefined type 'System.String' is not defined or imported  ApplicationName C:\Users\SuperUser\source\repos\ApplicationName\ApplicationName\Adapter\StorelistAdapter.cs 13  Active
Error   CS0518  Predefined type 'System.Void' is not defined or imported    ApplicationName C:\Users\SuperUser\source\repos\ApplicationName\ApplicationName\Adapter\StorelistAdapter.cs 15  Active
Error   CS0518  Predefined type 'System.String' is not defined or imported  ApplicationName C:\Users\SuperUser\source\repos\ApplicationName\ApplicationName\Adapter\StorelistAdapter.cs 15  Active
Error   CS0518  Predefined type 'System.Object' is not defined or imported  ApplicationName C:\Users\SuperUser\source\repos\ApplicationName\ApplicationName\Adapter\StorelistAdapter.cs 21  Active
Error   CS0246  The type or namespace name 'RecyclerView' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)  ApplicationName C:\Users\SuperUser\source\repos\ApplicationName\ApplicationName\Adapter\StorelistAdapter.cs 21  Active
Error   CS0518  Predefined type 'System.Object' is not defined or imported  ApplicationName C:\Users\SuperUser\source\repos\ApplicationName\ApplicationName\Adapter\StorelistAdapter.cs 21  Active
Error   CS0246  The type or namespace name 'ViewGroup' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) ApplicationName C:\Users\SuperUser\source\repos\ApplicationName\ApplicationName\Adapter\StorelistAdapter.cs 21  Active
Error   CS0518  Predefined type 'System.Int32' is not defined or imported   ApplicationName C:\Users\SuperUser\source\repos\ApplicationName\ApplicationName\Adapter\StorelistAdapter.cs 21  Active
Error   CS0518  Predefined type 'System.Void' is not defined or imported    ApplicationName C:\Users\SuperUser\source\repos\ApplicationName\ApplicationName\Adapter\StorelistAdapter.cs 35  Active
Error   CS0518  Predefined type 'System.Object' is not defined or imported  ApplicationName C:\Users\SuperUser\source\repos\ApplicationName\ApplicationName\Adapter\StorelistAdapter.cs 35  Active
Error   CS0246  The type or namespace name 'RecyclerView' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)  ApplicationName C:\Users\SuperUser\source\repos\ApplicationName\ApplicationName\Adapter\StorelistAdapter.cs 35  Active
Error   CS0518  Predefined type 'System.Int32' is not defined or imported   ApplicationName C:\Users\SuperUser\source\repos\ApplicationName\ApplicationName\Adapter\StorelistAdapter.cs 35  Active
Error   CS0518  Predefined type 'System.Int32' is not defined or imported   ApplicationName C:\Users\SuperUser\source\repos\ApplicationName\ApplicationName\Adapter\StorelistAdapter.cs 44  Active
Error   CS0115  'StorelistAdapter.ItemCount': no suitable method found to override  ApplicationName C:\Users\SuperUser\source\repos\ApplicationName\ApplicationName\Adapter\StorelistAdapter.cs 44  Active
Error   CS0518  Predefined type 'System.Void' is not defined or imported    ApplicationName C:\Users\SuperUser\source\repos\ApplicationName\ApplicationName\Adapter\StorelistAdapter.cs 46  Active
Error   CS0518  Predefined type 'System.Object' is not defined or imported  ApplicationName C:\Users\SuperUser\source\repos\ApplicationName\ApplicationName\Adapter\StorelistAdapter.cs 46  Active
Error   CS0518  Predefined type 'System.Void' is not defined or imported    ApplicationName C:\Users\SuperUser\source\repos\ApplicationName\ApplicationName\Adapter\StorelistAdapter.cs 47  Active
Error   CS0518  Predefined type 'System.Object' is not defined or imported  ApplicationName C:\Users\SuperUser\source\repos\ApplicationName\ApplicationName\Adapter\StorelistAdapter.cs 47  Active
Error   CS0246  The type or namespace name 'RecyclerView' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)  ApplicationName C:\Users\SuperUser\source\repos\ApplicationName\ApplicationName\Adapter\StorelistAdapter.cs 51  Active
Error   CS0518  Predefined type 'System.Void' is not defined or imported    ApplicationName C:\Users\SuperUser\source\repos\ApplicationName\ApplicationName\Adapter\StorelistAdapter.cs 56  Active
Error   CS0518  Predefined type 'System.Object' is not defined or imported  ApplicationName C:\Users\SuperUser\source\repos\ApplicationName\ApplicationName\Adapter\StorelistAdapter.cs 56  Active
Error   CS0246  The type or namespace name 'View' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)  ApplicationName C:\Users\SuperUser\source\repos\ApplicationName\ApplicationName\Adapter\StorelistAdapter.cs 56  Active
Error   CS0518  Predefined type 'System.Object' is not defined or imported  ApplicationName C:\Users\SuperUser\source\repos\ApplicationName\ApplicationName\Adapter\StorelistAdapter.cs 56  Active
Error   CS0246  The type or namespace name 'Action<>' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)  ApplicationName C:\Users\SuperUser\source\repos\ApplicationName\ApplicationName\Adapter\StorelistAdapter.cs 56  Active
Error   CS0518  Predefined type 'System.Object' is not defined or imported  ApplicationName C:\Users\SuperUser\source\repos\ApplicationName\ApplicationName\Adapter\StorelistAdapter.cs 56  Active
Error   CS0518  Predefined type 'System.Object' is not defined or imported  ApplicationName C:\Users\SuperUser\source\repos\ApplicationName\ApplicationName\Adapter\StorelistAdapter.cs 57  Active
Error   CS0246  The type or namespace name 'Action<>' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)  ApplicationName C:\Users\SuperUser\source\repos\ApplicationName\ApplicationName\Adapter\StorelistAdapter.cs 57  Active
Error   CS0518  Predefined type 'System.Object' is not defined or imported  ApplicationName C:\Users\SuperUser\source\repos\ApplicationName\ApplicationName\Adapter\StorelistAdapter.cs 57  Active
Error   CS0246  The type or namespace name 'EventArgs' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) ApplicationName C:\Users\SuperUser\source\repos\ApplicationName\ApplicationName\Adapter\StorelistAdapter.cs 65  Active
Error   CS0518  Predefined type 'System.Object' is not defined or imported  ApplicationName C:\Users\SuperUser\source\repos\ApplicationName\ApplicationName\Adapter\StorelistAdapter.cs 67  Active
Error   CS0246  The type or namespace name 'View' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)  ApplicationName C:\Users\SuperUser\source\repos\ApplicationName\ApplicationName\Adapter\StorelistAdapter.cs 67  Active
Error   CS0518  Predefined type 'System.Void' is not defined or imported    ApplicationName C:\Users\SuperUser\source\repos\ApplicationName\ApplicationName\Adapter\StorelistAdapter.cs 67  Active
Error   CS0518  Predefined type 'System.Int32' is not defined or imported   ApplicationName C:\Users\SuperUser\source\repos\ApplicationName\ApplicationName\Adapter\StorelistAdapter.cs 68  Active
Error   CS0518  Predefined type 'System.Void' is not defined or imported    ApplicationName C:\Users\SuperUser\source\repos\ApplicationName\ApplicationName\Adapter\StorelistAdapter.cs 68  Active
Error   CS0518  Predefined type 'System.Object' is not defined or imported  ApplicationName C:\Users\SuperUser\source\repos\ApplicationName\ApplicationName\Adapter\StorelistAdapter.cs 25  Active
Error   CS0246  The type or namespace name 'View' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)  ApplicationName C:\Users\SuperUser\source\repos\ApplicationName\ApplicationName\Adapter\StorelistAdapter.cs 25  Active
Error   CS0518  Predefined type 'System.Object' is not defined or imported  ApplicationName C:\Users\SuperUser\source\repos\ApplicationName\ApplicationName\Adapter\StorelistAdapter.cs 30  Active
Error   CS0518  Predefined type 'System.Object' is not defined or imported  ApplicationName C:\Users\SuperUser\source\repos\ApplicationName\ApplicationName\Adapter\StorelistAdapter.cs 30  Active
Error   CS1503  Argument 3: cannot convert from 'method group' to 'Action<StorelistAdapterClickEventArgs>'  ApplicationName C:\Users\SuperUser\source\repos\ApplicationName\ApplicationName\Adapter\StorelistAdapter.cs 30  Active
Error   CS0518  Predefined type 'System.Object' is not defined or imported  ApplicationName C:\Users\SuperUser\source\repos\ApplicationName\ApplicationName\Adapter\StorelistAdapter.cs 40  Active
Error   CS0518  Predefined type 'System.Array' is not defined or imported   ApplicationName C:\Users\SuperUser\source\repos\ApplicationName\ApplicationName\Adapter\StorelistAdapter.cs 44  Active
Error   CS0518  Predefined type 'System.Object' is not defined or imported  ApplicationName C:\Users\SuperUser\source\repos\ApplicationName\ApplicationName\Adapter\StorelistAdapter.cs 44  Active
Error   CS1061  'string[]' does not contain a definition for 'Length' and no accessible extension method 'Length' accepting a first argument of type 'string[]' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)    ApplicationName C:\Users\SuperUser\source\repos\ApplicationName\ApplicationName\Adapter\StorelistAdapter.cs 44  Active
Error   CS1729  'RecyclerView.ViewHolder' does not contain a constructor that takes 1 arguments ApplicationName C:\Users\SuperUser\source\repos\ApplicationName\ApplicationName\Adapter\StorelistAdapter.cs 57  Active
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, please make sure you have install these nuget packages.

[image]

And please check the following places.

1. Open your Adapter.cs, please notice the namespace of `RecyclerView.Adapter`, the correct namespace is `AndroidX.RecyclerView.Widget`

[image]

2. Namespace of the `RecyclerView` in layout.xml, In Android X, it should be changed `androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView` like following code.

```
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:id="@+id/recyclerView1"/>
```

3. Please Open your Activiy.cs, you package namespace of `LinearLayoutManager` and `RecyclerView` are `AndroidX.RecyclerView.Widget`

Here is GIF of my application running Android Q.

[image]

Here is my demo.

https://github.com/851265601/XAndroidX

Comment: Hi Leon, Tried your demo and its working fine. However, when i add firebase and googleplayservices, it reappears.

I guess its conflicting between those packages.


https://imgur.com/wJzgBCg

Comment: Please close your VS, and then Open your project folder; Delete the `bin` and `obj` folders; After reopen your project and build it.

Comment: this saves me from a lot of headache. thanks man, appreciate it.

Comment: Please don’t forget to mark this answer(click the ☑️ at the top right corner of this answer ), it will help others who have similar issues.